# A question in deleting duplicated index of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm preprocessing my dataset and find that there are some duplicated indexes.
I've tried to solve this problem with .drop_duplicates() function but failed.
And I turn to .duplicated() and it works...but I dont understand the difference between them.
The figure is a simple example.

[a simple example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFfkb.png)

I print(df.index.drop_duplicates(keep="first")) and it is correct, but after .loc the duplicated indexes still exist.
Could anyone help to explain the difference here please, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `df.index.duplicated` if you use `.loc` and not `df.index.drop_duplicates()` because the latter returns a list of unique indexes `['a', 'b']` so  `.loc` returns all rows where the index is found in this list. In fact, `df.index.drop_duplicates` has the same behavior as `df.index.unique()` here:

```
# Sample (slightly modified)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,0], 'B': [5,6,7,8,0], 'C': [9,10,11,12,0]}, 
                      index=['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'])

# Same as df.index.unique()
>>> df.index.drop_duplicates()
Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')

# Same as df.loc[df.index.unique()]
>>> df.loc[df.index.drop_duplicates(keep='first')]
   A  B   C
a  1  5   9
a  2  6  10
b  3  7  11
b  4  8  12
c  0  0   0

>>> df.loc[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
   A  B   C
a  1  5   9
b  3  7  11
c  0  0   0
```